# Submit app to Fabric fails with error code 0 or 502 or 503

Tags: ios, jenkins, xcodebuild, crashlytics

All of a sudden today I get these errors when submitting to Fabric:

```
2015-07-10 11:42:27.399 submit Crashlytics: Crashlytics.framework/submit 1.3.5 (15)
2015-07-10 11:42:48.689 submit Crashlytics: Unable to find application in Crashlytics. Response code: 0 
2015-07-10 11:42:48.690 submit Crashlytics: Does this app belong to this org? 
 We couldn't validate app with bundle ID jp.puroland.kisekae in the selected organization, so make sure you've first added your app through the Crashlytics app.
 You can check that your API key and build secret are correct by going here: https://crashlytics.com/settings/organizations
 Then select the org and click on API key or build secret underneath the org name.
```

I haven't really done any changes since yesterday when everything worked since a couple of months and weeks, as far as I know.

FWIV I did double check the API key and build secret. Nothing has changed. That stuff is all saved in a Jenkins job and I do not touch that.

Update: right now I get error code 502 instead of 0. Is that a HTTP response code? Server is bad?

Update: Now I get 503.

Comment: Finally I got a 200 response... and a build went through. Must have been a TEMPORARY HICKUP... guess I'll delete this after a while... if everything works for a while.

Comment: Okay back to 502. I guess this is one of those days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was a Crashlytics (but not Fabric) server-side issue. Like you, I hadn't changed anything that could affect ipa upload.

I'm in Japan too and I was getting "Unable to Reach Server" when I tried to login to the Crashlytics mac app. Instead I tried using command line via https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen and I got a similar error response (mine was 502 bad gateway) to what you saw. My API key/secret were fine.

About 30 mins ago the command line upload started working and 5 mins ago I was able to login to the Crashlytics mac app. And then doing an archive, and uploading the ipa through the mac app worked fine.

At all times I was able to login with my Crashlytics account to the dashboard fine.

I contacted Crashlytics support through the dashboard which may have helped get it resolved quickly.

Frustrating, but thankfully temporary.

Comment: That's nice. Builds through Jenkins still fail, then I cd into the work folder and try to upload manually. That has failed for some times and then it succeeds. So I'm still seeing less than 100% reliability.

Answer (score 0):

Today I am getting error "Unable to Reach Server" in login with Fabric Dashboard.

You can check fabric status From http://status.fabric.io/ some time fabric there may be change that issue is from server side.

Currently "Fabric dashboard not loading" so I check the status of Fabric and found that dashboard status is "Partial Outage". We may need to wait for fabric to fix it.

[image]